# DAC accuracy and calibration for an STM32 board

Tags: stm32, dac

I have [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) SM32F407 microcontroller board. I am step increasing its 12-bit DAC by 3 counts per step where its range is 0 to 4095 and amplifying the output with an opamp:

[image]

But I wonder how accurate is each step increase and don't know what to look at in the datasheet.

I wonder how much the maximum deviation for each DAC code(between 0 to 4095) in mV. What parameter shows that in the manual or [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00037051.pdf)?

And how is it possible to calibrate its DAC outputs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate DNL, INL, offset, and gain error.

DNL is the **D**ifferential **N**on-**L**inearity

This is the error in voltage levels between two consecutive voltage outputs.

INL is the **I**ntegral **N**on-**L**inearity

This is the difference between the ideal value as per the transfer function and reality.

The offset error is just the difference between the requested Vout and what you actually get.

The gain error represents the amount that the slope of the output may be off.

These are reported starting on page 140 of your datasheet.  While interpreting those values, LSB stands for **L**east **S**ignificant **B**its.

I do not believe there is any way to calibrate a DAC of this type.  You can play with the Vref to help a bit with offset, but you will pretty well have to live with the error.  Keeping your supply and reference voltages clean is about the best you can do.